# How to use regex to find a specific word from text and return all occurences?

Tags: python, regex

Just like the question title.

I'm new to Python and regular expressions. Hereby I have to search for a specific word from a paragraph and show all indices of occurrence.

For example:

the paragraph is:

> This is a testing text and used to test and test and test.

and the word:

> test

The algorithm should return the index of non-overlapping occurences of 3 words **test** in the above paragraph (but not ***testing***, because I mean search the whole word, not just substring).

Another example with the same paragraph and this "word":

> test and

The algorithm should return 2 occurrences of **test and**.

I guess I must use some regular expressions to find the pattern of that whole word, with preceding and following are punctuations such as `. , ; ? -`

After Googling I found something like `re.finditer` should be used but it seems that I haven't found out the right way to go. Please help, thank you in advance. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) is the way to go. Use [`start()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) to find the index of the match.

---

**Example:**

```
import re

a="This is a testing text and used to test and test and test."
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"\btest\b", a)]
print [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"\btest and\b", a)]
```

**Output:**

> [35, 44, 53]
>   [35, 44]

Answer (score 3):

Use word boundary anchor `\b` in your regex to indicate you want match to start/end at word boundary.

```
>>> sentence = "This is a testing text and used to test and test and test."
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\btest\b')
>>> [m.start() for m in pattern.finditer(sentence)]
[35, 44, 53]
```